# Non-nullable instance field ['controller'] must be initialized in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable, dart-null-safety, non-nullable

Good day!
I am a new to Flutter to would like to start my Startup but I was trapped in this problem to make Tabbar example...

I have almost been frustrated all day because of this problems....

Dart Analysis keeps saying this below....

Non-nullable instance field ['controller'] must be initialized in flutter

really appreciate in advance.

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sub/firstPage.dart';
import 'sub/secondPage.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);



  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBar Example'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[FirstApp(), SecondApp()],
          controller: controller,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one, color: Colors.blue),),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two, color: Colors.blue),),
        ],
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plase try, you missed use controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sub/firstPage.dart';
import 'sub/secondPage.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);



  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBar Example'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[FirstApp(), SecondApp()],
          controller: controller,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          controller: controller, // add here 
          tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one, color: Colors.blue),),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two, color: Colors.blue),),
        ],
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your field does not allow null values, but you cannot initialize your field when it's created, you have to declare it as `late`:

```
late TabController controller;
```

This allows you to assign a value later, but you *will* get an exception if you use it before it was assigned. The way your code looks, it should be okay.

Comment: ...and if it doesn't work, just do not forget to restart your app)) it was my problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using null safety in your project. So the dart is complaining about this line. Dart expects it to be initialized right after it was created:

```
TabController controller;
```

To fix the problem add the "late" keyword before TabController:

```
late TabController controller;
```